# Access Redis cluster in docker network from local non-docker app

Tags: docker-compose

I am new to docker and specifically networking. I have a docker-compose.yml file that brings up a Redis Cluster on a subnet called redis_subnet. I have a Java Springboot application that connects to the Redis Cluster using the endpoint and port. Normally I would connect via localhost and 6373 (I have a bash script that brings up redis nodes and stitches them together to make a cluster. Non-docker) but I'm unable to with the redis cluster that is brought up via docker.

```
version: '3'
services:  
  redis-cluster:
    image: redis:6.0-alpine
    command: redis-cli --cluster create 172.20.0.31:6373 172.20.0.32:6374 172.20.0.33:6375 172.20.0.34:6376 172.20.0.35:6377 172.20.0.36:6378 --cluster-replicas 1 --cluster-yes
    networks:
      redis_subnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.30
    depends_on:
      - redis-node-1
      - redis-node-2
      - redis-node-3
      - redis-node-4
      - redis-node-5
      - redis-node-6
  redis-node-1:
    image: redis:6.0-alpine
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - '6373:6373'
    volumes:
      - redis-node-1-data:/var/lib/redis
      - ./docker/redis-node-1.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    networks:
      redis_subnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.31
  ...
networks:
  redis_subnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
```

From logs, I can see that the redis cluster comes up and all the nodes are stitched together to make a cluster. But I am unable to connect to it via the application or `redis-cli cluster info` . I am hoping to expose the redis cluster brought up via docker so that I can connect it from my host machine.

I have tried adding a gateway as seen below since I see the same for in the default network, but I assume this does not do what I expect it does.

```
networks:
  redis_subnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
        - gateway: 172.21.0.1
```